# WordPress - wp-admin blank page

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I am currently unable to get into my WP Dashboard.  The wp-admin page is completely blank throwing no visible errors.  I can hit wp-login.php, use my login credentials and hit Log In and then again just blank page, still not logged in.  The site it self works fine.

I did enable wp_debug and this still is not showing any errors.

I just took over this site so I do not know of any recent updates or changes made to themes,plugins etc.

UPDATE: I was able to get wp-admin page to load the wp-login page properly by just uploading a clean version of wp-admin/index.php.  However I am still seeing a blank page and unable to login after hitting 'log in'

I check the error logs for the server and I do not see anything related to this site.

Comment: Look at your web server's error logs to see if there's any hints as to what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that u don't have blank spaces in config and functions file at the top or bottom of theses.

btw, it seems like server's error. See his log :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a PHP error. 
Add:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

To the top of wp-admin/index.php

Answer (score 0):

A common troubleshooting technique would be to rename your

> ./wp-content/plugins

folder. This will temporarily deactivate all your plugins. Often such issues are caused by a malfunctioning plugin, usually after an automated update.

Another thing you can try is to switch the php version of your hosting account. Most hosting companies run CloudLinux and you have in cPanel -> Select PHP Version. You can test the administrator login with different versions.

You can also contact your webhosting provider and have them check if the ConfigServer eXploit Scanner (cxs), often installed on shared servers hasn't quarantined any of your website files.

It might be a long shot, but it is also worth checking your .htaccess file.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused from an error in your theme functions file. If you have a theme backup (which you are sure worked before), try restoring it from the file manager in your host panel. If you don't, try uploading a popular wordpress theme (e.g. twenty-sixteen) then change your default theme from PhpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your root folder, open wp-config.php,...

Enable Debug mode.(i.e)

define('WP_DEBUG', false);
to 
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

And inspect it using Firebug.